# Где завести временный svn?

Tags: svn, google-code

Я студент. Надо сделать некоторую программу совместно (+-2 человека). Для этого я хочу использовать svn. Естественно, что после выполнения моя работа врятли кому то понадобится - но мне не жалко.

Выход - я создал проект на *Google Code*. Но мне как-то стало стыдно засорять такой серьёзный сервер своими недоделками. Есть ли у вас идеи лучше?

Comment: Как вариант посмотри bitbucket.org, как раз для проекта на 5 человек вполне подойдет, правда он на основе mercurial, а не svn.

Comment: как вариант можно и свой SVN поднять

Comment: это как стыдно - засорять google?
а засорять этим хэшкод - не стыдно?
то,что студент - не прощает и не умаляет глупость,тем паче программисту.
зы. если не можешь выбрать и прикидываешься "бедным студентом",которому прощалось раньше многое,теперь бедных студентов нет,то иди на штукатура

Comment: 2 @tukan: это не глупость, а неуверенность в себе, с другой стороны действительно автор вопроса поступает нелогично (не засорять гугл, но засорять хэшкод), что есть плохо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Хостинг Google Code - один из лучших.
2. После завершения проекта, вы всегда можете удалить его.
3. Возможно, что то, что вы в итоге сделаете, будет качественной работой.

Поэтому зачем отказываться от него?

Кроме Google Code часто работают с [github](https://github.com/blog/626-announcing-svn-support) и [bitbucket](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Accessing+your+bitbucket+Repository+via+Subversion;jsessionid=25B3D805A9F702248EE719E4E518F19B). С обоими можно работать через svn (хотя я не пробовал.)

Answer (score 1):

Использовал для таких же целей бесплатный приватный репозиторий на [Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/one_page_signup/free-private-subversion-repository-only). Ваш код никто кроме вашей комманды не увидит. Если получится ерунда - не стыдно, а если что-то стоящее - не обязательно отдавать в open source.

Answer (score 0):

[xp-dev.com](http://xp-dev.com) отличный сайт. Уже пару лет там работаем небольшой командой + баг и таск трэкер в подарок))

Answer (score 0):

http://sourceforge.net/ когда-то использовал